# jsqlparser to evaluate a condition

Tags: java, parsing, visitor-pattern, jsqlparser

The following String:

```
x=92 and y=29
```

Produces a valid output: `x=92 AND y=29` and it works fine with `CCJSqlParserUtil.parseCondExpression` but shouldn't it throw an exception for the following?

```
x=92 lasd y=29
```

But the output is just: `x=92`

Furthermore which Expression I should use to implement my own visitor? i.e,

```
CCJSqlParser c= new CCJSqlParser(new StringReader(str));
Expression e = c.Expression(); // or SimpleExpression, etc..
```

So that when 'lasd' (anything other than not,or,and) is encountered I can throw an exception and not silently ignore the rest of the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently a patch of **JSqlParser (1.2-SNAPSHOT)** was published to provide the needed behaviour:

```
CCJSqlParserUtil.parseExpression(String expression, boolean allowPartialParse)
```

and

```
CCJSqlParserUtil.parseCondExpression(String expression, boolean allowPartialParse)
```

Setting **allowPartialParse** to **false** will result in the mentioned **Exception**.

For on the fly interpreted stuff the already existing behaviour is still needed, e.g. to provide expressions from within an text. (Syntax coloring, Context help, ...)